# rosdep: error: Unsupported command update

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

clean installation of fuerte, and when I tried to run rosdep update I got:

```
rosdep: error: Unsupported command update.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37391/rosdep:-error:-unsupported-command-update./) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the output of:

```
rosdep --version
```

You're probably using rosdep from an older distribution.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-06-27**:
You are probably right, the installation wasn't so clean as I thought.